# PDFJS Angular 2

Tags: angular, webpack, pdf.js

I have integrated PDFJS with angular2 based project (https://github.com/VadimDez/ng2-pdf-viewer):

```
import 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.combined';
import 'pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer';
import { getDocument,  PDFJS } from "pdfjs-dist";
```

and in package.json :

```
"@types/pdf": "0.0.31",
"pdfjs-dist": "^1.7.244"
```

I have this error when running the project :

```
[default] /Users/developperdevelopper/Documents/work/workspace/auth-server_v2/www/src/app/pages/esigner/esigner.component.ts:263:25 
Cannot find name 'PDFDocumentProxy'.
Cannot find name 'PDFSource'.
```

Comment: You may be referring to mozilla's npm package. The angular wrapper package is "npm install ng2-pdf-viewer --save"